# Is there a perl module to validate passwords stored in "{crypt}hashedpassword" "{ssha}hashedpassword" "{md5}hashedpassword"

Tags: perl, encryption, crypt

I have a table which stores user login infomration, which contains passwords in the below scheme:

- {crypt}hashedpassword
- {ssha}hashedpasswordsalted
- {md5}hashedpassword
- .....

Is there a Perl module that understands this scheme and is able to validate the password given the plain text password?

Something like

> print "success!!\n" if validatePassword("helloworld",{CRYPT}r2sKInajXZ6Fk)

Answer (score 6):

[Authen::Passphrase](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Authen::Passphrase) can do this:

```
use Authen::Passphrase;

print "success!!\n" 
  if Authen::Passphrase->from_rfc2307('{CRYPT}r2sKInajXZ6Fk')->match("helloworld");
```